# Simulating lack of a dependency when testing a python script

Tags: python, testing, module, import, dependencies

What's the best way to temporarily hide an installed module from a python script to test how it handles environments that don't have the module installed?

I'd like to avoid having to uninstall the module just to test.

Comment: @Michael: You mean just don't import it? I suppose I could do that, that just wouldn't be testing my conditional import, which isn't a big deal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import sys
sys.modules['numpy']=None
```

Setting `sys.modules['numpy']=None` makes Python think that it has already tried and failed to import `numpy`. Subsequent attempts at importing `numpy` now raise `ImportError`:

```
try:
    import numpy
except ImportError as err:
    print(err)
    # No module named numpy
```

Deleting `sys.modules['numpy']` allows `numpy` to be imported as normal:

```
del sys.modules['numpy']
import numpy
```

Answer (score 3):

Change  your Python Path.

The order of directories in `sys.path` shows the order of a search.

You can change `sys.path` in a test to alter the search order.

Comment: just make sure to put it back afterwards!

Comment: @Winston Ewert: "Afterwords?"  Unit tests has "setUp" and "tearDown" to alter the environment, is that what you're talking about?